# Can ubuntu have persistent storage on a sd card

Tags: sd-card, persistence

Can you have persistent storage on SD card?

I heard you can for USB, but does it work with a SD card?

Answer (score 1):

You can have persistent storage on a SD card, it's even one of the installation method for numerous ARM development boards such as the PandaBoard:

Visit: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/QA/Pandaboard